# FadeIn and AppendTo does not work - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

I'm working on a simple web project as you can find here: http://seegermattijs.be/pickone/
When the item is being added, i use the following code in jQuery:

```
$("<h2>"+inputfield+"</h2><br/>").hide().appendTo(".items").fadeIn();
```

Unfortunately the items don't fadeIn. This is not the only problem. Also the pick one button should fade in and when you push the pick one button, everything should fade out. None of these work :(

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the code given works as described. http://jsfiddle.net/3XkkH/1/ - and it isn't the code that's running on the page you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("<h2 style='display:none'>"+inputfield+"</h2><br/>").appendTo(".items").fadeIn('slow');
```

it useless to use a method for do something you can write in the string...

`style='display:none'` not `.hide()`

sorry i don't understand what you mean:
"This is not the only problem. Also the pick one button should fade in and when you push the pick one button, everything should fade out. None of these work :("

:( my english is soo bad...

NB.
if you not need delete `<br/>` is useless because `<H2>` is alewady a block HMLT item...

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's still the same. It seems that none of the fadeIn effects work. The 'pick one' button should also fade in: $('.resultBtn').fadeIn(); even that doesn't work

Comment: wait... write the valie of inputfield variable.